# Indirect question vs objective clause

Tags: clauses, indirect-question

Which is right:

> Do you think it's a good idea to visit in mid August?

Or

> Do you think ***if*** it's a good idea to visit in mid August?

On one hand, if viewed as indirect question, `if` should not be omitted for clarity. But on the other hand, if viewed as objective clause, `it's a good idea ...` is the object of `think`, which makes `if` redundant. What's the correct grammar here?

Comment: No, you can't have an _if_-clause complement after _think_. _Wonder,_ yes, and also _know_, but _wonder_ rarely takes a _that_-clause complement. WIth _know_, they both work: _Do you know (that/if) it's a good idea to visit in mid-August?_ -- either _that_ or _if_ may be used, or neither.

Comment: What @John said. But note that *that/if* aren't always equivalent after *know*. For example, in *So your wife's pregnant! Do you know **that** you're the father?* it means ***whether*** (speaker doesn't know). But in *Do you know **that** it's my birthday today?* it means ***the fact that*** (obviously the speaker knows perfectly well if it's her birthday or not! :)

Comment: One thing I wanted to point out... isn't it bad english to say "On one hand" as qweruiop did in his question? Shouldn't he have said "On the one hand" ?